# PostGIS multiple spatial joins in the same query

Tags: postgis, postgresql

While I understand how I would do something like this in non-spatial SQL, I have confused about how I would join data from more than two joins in one query in spatial SQL.

I have a table of zipcode polygons 'Z', a table of restaurant polygons 'F' and restaurant points 'FP'. What I would like to produce as a result is a table with a row for each zip code and columns for the count of the restaurant polygons, the count of restaurant points, and the sum of both restaurant columns within each zip code.

As a test, I am only using 1 zipcode. First just getting the restaurant points:

```
SELECT z.modzcta,COUNT(f.name)
FROM osm.food_point f
INNER JOIN osm.modzcta z
ON ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(z.geom,3857),f.way)
WHERE z.modzcta = '11238'
GROUP BY z.modzcta;
```

returns `[('11238', 192)]`

Then, using the polygons:

```
SELECT z.modzcta,COUNT(fp.name)
FROM osm.food_polygon fp
INNER JOIN osm.modzcta z
ON ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(z.geom,3857),fp.way)
WHERE z.modzcta = '11238'
GROUP BY z.modzcta;
```

I get `[('11238', 10)]`

When I try to combine these two together:

```
SELECT z.modzcta,COUNT(fp.name) res_points, COUNT(f.name) res_polygons, COUNT(fp.name) + COUNT(f.name) total_rest
FROM osm.food_polygon f
INNER JOIN osm.modzcta z
ON ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(z.geom,3857),f.way)
INNER JOIN osm.food_point fp
ON ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(z.geom,3857),fp.way)
WHERE z.modzcta = '11238'
GROUP BY z.modzcta;
```

I get `[('11238', 1920, 1930, 3850)]`

I'm not sure what is going on here.

Also as an aside, is there any way to return the column names with the result of a query in the psycopg2 python module?

Comment: It looks like the results are cummulative @jboges - have a look at this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216440/multiple-spatial-joins-in-postgis 
in regards to the column names with psycop2 this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252247/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-column-names-from-a-psycopg2-cursor

Comment: This does provide me with the correct result. Thank you. I understand why DISTINCT works in this scenario, however I am confused on exactly why there are so many more results than expected when using ST_Intersect. I would expect it to only 'join' the tables by the common geography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JOIN` chain multiplies rows of the middle table for every pair of rows of the right-most table (i.e. `192 point * 10 polygons = 1920 total point counts`).

While `DISTINCT` works in this case (it may not in others), the `JOIN` chain is still highly inefficient due to the unnecessary duplication; better use a *correlated sub-query*, or better even, a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`:

```
SELECT z.modzcta, r_pnt.cnt, r_ply.cnt
FROM   osm.modzcta AS z
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT COUNT(f.*) AS cnt
  FROM   osm.food_point AS f
  WHERE  ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(z.geom,3857),f.way)
) AS r_pnt
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT COUNT(f.*) AS cnt
  FROM   osm.food_polygon AS f
  WHERE  ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(z.geom,3857),f.way)
) AS r_ply
;
```

Make sure there is a `GIST` index on the geometry columns of both join tables.

Comment: Definitely the right way to go!