# Counting categorized points in polygons using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, aggregation

I want to do an operation i PostGIS similar to the `count points in polygon` in QGIS.

I have

- A multipolygon table (`plan.polygon`) consisting of several areas
- A point table (`basemap.points`)

in a PostGIS database.

The point layer is categorized by the column `code_text`.

I want to count the number of each category for each of areas resulting in a multipolygon table with rows areas and columns with the count of each category.

Below you can se the areas (red lines) and the points with categorization (red, yellow, green dots).

[image]

I've been trying the following resulting in a query processing forever.

```
SELECT b.gid, b.the_geom, 
    (SELECT COUNT(v.code_text)
    FROM basemap.points v, plan.polygon x
    WHERE entity = 120 AND ST_within(v.the_geom, x.the_geom)
GROUP BY a.code_text) 
AS count_category_a,
    (SELECT count(y.code_text)
    FROM basemap.points y, plan.polygona z
    WHERE entity = 130 AND ST_within(y.the_geom, z.the_geom)
GROUP BY a.code_text) 
AS count_category_b
FROM basemap.points a, plan.polygons b;
```

Comment: Not knowing your table setup but this looks like a LEFT JOIN is required https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54661/counting-points-in-polygon-with-postgis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a simple [filtered aggregate?](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

Try

```
SELECT ply.gid,
       COUNT(pts.*) FILTER (WHERE pt.code_text = <category_a>) AS count_category_a,
       COUNT(pts.*) FILTER (WHERE pt.code_text = <category_b>) AS count_category_b,
       COUNT(pts.*) FILTER (WHERE pt.code_text = <category_c>) AS count_category_c,
       ply.the_geom
FROM   plan.polygons AS ply
JOIN   basemap.points AS pts
  ON   ST_Intersects(ply.geom, pts.geom)
GROUP BY
       ply.gid, ply.geom
;
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.
If I want to add columns (counts) based on another spatial join, how can I put the code then? I have another point layer with categorization that needs to be added to the same table. Can I handle this bu using a subquery or the same join?

Comment: @kwiwe Another `JOIN` on the same table and predicate would result in a (n highly inefficient) cartesian product between both joined tables, and would require to `DISTINCT` the counts. *Correlated subqueries* are one way, `LATERAL` queries probably the more performant. See my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384461/93656) to get you going; you'd want to move the filtered counts into the `LATERAL` sub-queries, and `SUM` in the outer.